# PostBack from a link in Grid within UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a grid and few textboxes within an UpdatePanel. On selecting a paricular row the textboxes are filled using JS. UpdatePanel was introduced as one textbox was filled using a method in the code.
There is also a link in grid row which opens a pop-up(also filled from code behind).

After using UpdatePanel the link is not working(assuming because of no full post back).

I tried using UpdateMode="Conditional" property and registering Link control for PostBAck control.
But still it is not working:

Code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server" Up>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvSession" BorderColor="#ffcc00" RowStyle-BorderColor="#ffcc00"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Verdana" DataKeyNames="SessionId" runat="server"
                            RowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" RowStyle-BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both" Width="100%"
                            OnRowCreated="gvSession_RowCreated" OnDataBound="gvSession_DataBound">
                            <RowStyle CssClass="dbGrid_Table_row" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="dbGrid_Table_Header" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelect" onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVIDMore(this);"
                                            runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rbSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Session Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSessionName" Text='<%# Eval("SessionName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="16%"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPreview" Text="Preview" CommandName="Preview" AutoPostBack="true"
                                         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SessionId")  + ";" +  Eval("TrainingTypeName") %>'
                                            runat="server" OnClick="lbPreview_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                               </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="Table2" runat="server" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSessionDtl" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Style="text-align: center"
                            ForeColor="Black" Wrap="true" Height="20px" Width="95%" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 12%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" CssClass="label" runat="server">Upload File : </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilePath" Enabled="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black"
                            runat="server" Width="741px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

FOr Link click:

```
protected void lbPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gv = (GridViewRow)(link.Parent.Parent);
            LinkButton linkPreview = (LinkButton)gv.FindControl("lbPreview");
            string[] arg = new string[2];
            arg = linkPreview.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
            string strSessionId = arg[0];
            string strTrgType = arg[1];
            string mailContent = GenerateNominationMailer(strSessionId, strTrgType);
            hidMailContent.Value = mailContent;
            string mailContent1 = mailContent.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");

            string myScript = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>";
            myScript = myScript + " my_window = window.open('', '', 'status=1,width=1000,height=800,scrollbars=yes');";
            myScript = myScript + " my_window.document.write(\"" + mailContent1.Replace("\"", "'") + "\");";
            myScript = myScript + " my_window.document.close();";
            myScript = myScript + " </script>";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Nomination Mailer", myScript,false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AlnErrorHandler.HandleError(ex);

        }
    }
```

For registering control:

```
 protected void gvSession_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grdrow in gvSession.Rows)
        {
            LinkButton Preview = (LinkButton)grdrow.FindControl("lbPreview");
            ScriptManager current = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
            if (current != null)
                current.RegisterPostBackControl(Preview);
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

set trigger for your event. put this at end of ContentTemplate

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbPreview" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
```

Comment: I am getting this error-A control with ID 'lbPreview' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'Update'

Comment: Ok Got it your control is inside grid thats why this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Replace your old event with this

```
protected void gvSession_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
   LinkButton Preview = e.Row.FindControl("lbPreview") as LinkButton;  
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Preview);  
}
```

and assign gvSession_DataBound event in GridView as DataBound event

Comment: e.Row is not being resolved so..I put it like this.. foreach (GridViewRow grdrow in gvSession.Rows)
            {
                LinkButton Preview = (LinkButton)grdrow.FindControl("lbPreview");
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Preview);  
               
            }.......................................but this also is not working..even when on debugging the methos is called and everything..I am just not getting the reason :( :(